# How to use multiple assignment with a ternary operator?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, variable-assignment, ternary-operator

this works:

```
foo, bar = 1, 2
foo == 1  #true
bar == 2  #true
```

this also works:

```
baz = true
foo = baz ? 1 : 2
foo == 1  #true
```

this **does not** work:

```
foo, bar = baz ? 1, 2 : 3, 4
# SyntaxError: (irb):4: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting ':'
# foo, bar = baz ? 1, 2 : 3, 4
#                    ^
```

How should this be formatted so that it works?

Comment: When parsing the first comma in your third expression the exception `"syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting ':'"` is raised. That is because `1, 2` is not a Ruby object.

Comment: @AryaMcCarthy, good question. I forgot to include the error response. Thanks to whoever edited my question :)

Comment: Also, the `unexpected ','` is likely just Ruby doing it's best to identify the flaw. I have outlined the corrected syntax below.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here is the correct syntax for multiple assignment using a ternary operator:

```
foo, bar = baz ? [1, 2] : [3, 4]
```

The return values for true and false must be wrapped in brackets.

I hope this helps :)

Comment: This does not answer your question.

Comment: I agree, this answer may solve the original problem (not described in the question), but its not an answer to the question. Not sure how it got an upvote.

Comment: It answers (or provides a solution to) the _"How to use multiple assignment with a ternary operator?"_ part.

Comment: I answered my own question. Perhaps I should have been more clear. 

I wasn't exactly trying to find out _why_ `foo, bar = baz ? 1, 2 : 3, 4` doesn't work, but rather how to format the syntax correctly for multiple assignment with a ternary operator... To that end, I believe it does solve the problem. 

I'm of the opinion that the longest most drawn out explanation isn't always the best answer. As Shakespeare said, "brevity is the soul of wit".

As such, I will happily revise my question to exclude "why?"

Why did it receive an upvote? Because it solve the problem of _how_.

Answer (score 8):

> `foo, bar = baz ? 1, 2 : 3, 4` <= this DOES NOT work... why?

Here's why:

If you look at [`parse.y`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/parse.y) (the grammar of Ruby), the ternary conditional structure `arg1 ? arg2 : arg3` needs `arg` (an argument) for its arguments:

```
arg     : lhs '=' arg_rhs
        | # ...
        | arg '?' arg opt_nl ':' arg
        | # ...
```

and

```
arg_rhs : arg
        # ...
```

As seen above, the assignment `lhs = rhs` is also an `arg`. But multiple assignment `mlhs1, mlhs2 = mrhs1, mrhs2` is a *statement*:

```
stmt    : # ...
        | mlhs '=' mrhs_arg
        | # ...
        | expr
        ;
```

And while an argument can be used as an expression

```
expr    : # ...
        | arg
        ;
```

and an expression can be used as a statement as seen above, the reverse is not true: a statement is not always a valid expression, and an expression is not always a valid argument.

Furthermore, when you have `[1, 2]`, that's an array, which is a valid `arg`, which is also a valid `arg_rhs`, which can go in the right side of `arg : lhs '=' arg_rhs`. `1, 2` is not a valid `arg`, but it *is* a valid `mrhs_arg` (multiple right-side built up of arguments, which either has multiple comma-separated values like `foo, bar = 1, 2`, `foo, bar = *[1, 2]` or even `foo, bar = 1, *[2]`, or destructures an array value like `foo, bar = [1, 2]`):

```
mrhs_arg : mrhs
         | arg_value
         ;

mrhs     : args ',' arg_value
         # ...
         | args ',' tSTAR arg_value
         # ...
         | tSTAR arg_value
         # ...
         ;
```

so it fits right in into the `stmt : mlhs '=' mrhs_arg` rule.

This last rule is also the reason why your solution `foo, bar = baz ? [1, 2] : [3, 4]` works: `baz ? [1, 2] : [3, 4]` is an `arg`, which is also `arg_value`, and can be used in the `mrhs_arg : arg_value` rule. But the rule with explicit bare commas that allows `foo, bar = 1, 2` (`mrhs : args ',' arg_value`) cannot be used with a conditional, because it explicitly requires at least two comma-separated arguments - which is not a possible result from a conditional.

**tl;dr:** Because multiple assignment is parsed differently than simple assignment.